# What is the reason for response not ready error in Mining Social web?

Tags: httplib

```
import httplib2
import json
import apiclient.discovery # pip install google-api-python-client

# XXX: Enter any person's name
Q = "Vamsi"

# XXX: Enter in your API key from  https://code.google.com/apis/console

API_KEY = ''

service = apiclient.discovery.build('plus', 'v1', http=httplib2.Http(), 
                                    developerKey=API_KEY)

people_feed = service.people().search(query=Q).execute()

print json.dumps(people_feed['items'], indent=1)
```

Comment: I run the above code and It used to run perfectly before, now it is showing ResponseNotReady Error. What's the solution?

Comment: Please edit your question to format your code using markdown. [Editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)